# Javascript Submit Back to Form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am building a search by city function. Once you have typed in the search field, and if there are multiple cities, you are then presented with all the options. 
Each option is a link with javascript, which when clicked should input the value (zipcode) back into the form for processing. The error I am getting is this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined

Here is my javascript (yep Im using smarty):

```
<a href= "#" onclick="document['myform'].submit({$row.Zipcode}); return false">{$row.City}, {$row.State} {$row.Zipcode}</a>
```

Here is my form:

```
<form action="mymethod.php" method="POST" id="myform">
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the zipcode back to the form for processing upon 'click'
Appreciate any insight anyone cares to share

Comment: By `document['myform']` did you mean `document.getElementById('myform')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.forms` collection has named elements, which refer to `<form>` elements with a corresponding `name` attribute.

To refer to your form, add `name="myForm"`.

```
<form action="mymethod.php" method="POST" name="myform">
```

Instead of using a link, I strongly recommend to use a `<input type="submit">` element, to not drive away users who have disabled JavsScript.

Comment: thanks rob i appreciate you taking the time to answer my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="javascript:$('#myform').submit({$row.Zipcode}); return false"
```

Comment: Why do you assume that he's using jQuery..?

Comment: I feel an urge to downvot that comment, even though it's not possible. *Everyone does!* is **not** a valid argument for recommending jQuery over plain javaScript. jQuery is relatively slow, especially if you're including it *just* for a simple element-by-id selection.

Answer (score 0):

Name you form instead: `<form action="mymethod.php" method="POST" name="myform">`

Then call it using: `document.forms["myform"]`