# What is meant by Javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined"?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

What is meant by Javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined"?

I am trying to add an item to cart in my Magneto site. But it shows the above error. Can you point out its meaning or possible reason behind the error such that i can try deeper?

Comment: You are trying to call the submit method of a particular object and that object doesn't have such a method. In fact the object is undefined so it won't have any methods. As such we would need more specific code to suggest a solution.

Comment: check the form nam,e you have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as it says: you have an `undefined` value, and trying to call a method called `submit` on it, like this:

```
undefined.submit();
```

or like this:

```
var nonexistent;
nonexistent.submit();
```

or even like this:

```
var threeElementArray = [1, 2, 3];
threeElementArray[100].submit();
```

Why would a library raise it, I don't know. You are not providing much details. It can either be a bug in their code, or more likely you're giving it incorrect parameters somewhere.

Comment: Thank you... It may be a Jquery conflict I think.

Answer (score 0):

There's another Stack Overflow question on a similar subject, perhaps this could help you?

[Javascript Submit Back to Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933932/javascript-submit-back-to-form)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you are trying to submit the form using the submit method. But possibly the form object on which you are trying to call the submit method, is not exists in the document.

May be you mis-typed the form id or name or something like that.